# Refactor ugly if/else statement in Rails View

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this nasty if/else statement in a rails view:

```
         <% if question.field_type == "text_area" %>
            <%= f.text_area :content, :class=>"form-control question-field", :data => {:question => question.id, :filter=> @filter}, :value=> question.answer(@assessment).try(:content) %>
          <% elsif question.field_type == "date" %>
            <%= f.date_select :content, { :order => [:year, :month, :day], :prompt => { :day => 'day', :month => 'month', :year=> "year" }, :end_year=> Date.today.year, :start_year => Date.today.year - 2 }, {:class => "question-field", :data => {:question => question.id, :filter=> @filter}, :value=> question.answer(@assessment).try(:content)} %>
          <% elsif question.field_type == "text_field" %>
            <%= f.text_field :content, :class=>"form-control question-field", :value=> question.answer(@assessment).try(:content), :data => {:question => question.id, :filter=> @filter} %>
         <% elsif question.field_type == "dropdown" %>
           <%= f.select :content, options_for_select(question.options), { :prompt => "Choose One..." }, :class=>"form-control question-field", :value=> question.answer(@assessment).try(:content), :data => {:question => question.id, :filter=> @filter} %>
          <% elsif question.field_type == "number" %>
           <%= f.select :content, options_for_select(1..10), {:include_blank=> true}, :class=>"form-control question-field", :value=> question.answer(@assessment).try(:content), :data => {:question => question.id, :filter=> @filter} %>
          <% elsif question.field_type == "percentage" %>
             <h2>100%</h2>
             <%= f.range_field :content, :value=> get_percentage(question), :class=> "question-field percentage", :data => {:question => question.id, :filter=> @filter}, :step => 25, :in => 0..100 %> 
          <% end %>
```

Is there a good way to refactor this to make it nicer? This piece of code is in every field:

```
:class=>"form-control question-field", :value=> question.answer(@assessment).try(:content), :data => {:question => question.id, :filter=> @filter}
```

Do I refactor into a helper method or a partial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes templates are just messy and you can only clean up detail.  Refactoring into a parameterized partial will help. For goodness sake, use a `case`.  And consider switching to HAML.  It eliminates a lot of the visual clutter.

```
<%= render 'question_field', f: f, type: question.field_type %>
```

Then in `_question_field.erb`,

```
<%= case type %>
  <% when 'text_area' %>
    <% f.text_area :content, class: 'form-control question-field', %>
        <% data: { question: question.id, filter: @filter }, %>
        <% value: question.answer(@assessment).try(:content) %>
  <% when ... %>
<% end %>
```

Note common industrial practice is to pick a max line length and stick to it: 100 and 120 are pretty common. Also, use the new symbol key notation for hashes. The old hook-and-arrow is too noisy.

In HAML:

```
= case type
  - when 'text_area'
    - f.text_area :content, class: 'form-control question-field',
      data: { question: question.id, filter: @filter },
      value: question.answer(@assessment).try(:content)
  - when ...
```

Comment: Why is a case statement better than if/else ?

Comment: This is not true that templates are sometimes messy. If we're vigilant enough - they can be clean and simple. I would think about partials here, because this is what they are for (check out my answer).

Answer (score 0):

I would get rid of if's and when's altogether by creating seperate partial for every possibility, then you just end up with:

```
<%= render question.field_type, locals: {question: question} %>
```

Or to make it even cleaner for view make helper method and call only

```
<%= question_field(question) %>
```

and this method would look little bit like

```
def question_field(question)
  return render question.field_type, locals: {question: question}
  # raise when no partial found, or do something elese
end
```